# Bulk Update User Permission in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, share

I was wondering if there is a way to Bulk Update the User permission across site collection? for instance i have this user whose permission has to be Downgraded from Full Control to Reader only and i figured he has been granted a Permission directly across 200 different Objects ( Site, List,Library, Item) also includes several custom permission.

Comment: Is PowerShell an option for you? By "Permission", are you saying "Permission Level"? Have these users also been added to groups, and do they need to also be changed?

Comment: Yes the "Permission Level". These particular user are not part of GROUPS ( are granted permissions directly) but i have got few other users who are added to groups and i am trying to do downgrade permission level for them as well. And Yes Power shell is an Option.